# Convert decimals into whole numbers and finding the difference between two columns

Tags: hive, hql, hiveql

I have two columns like below:

```
A      |  B
0.33   |  0.55
0.44   |  0.65
10     |  20
10.1   |  10.234
11.236 |  12.8963
12     |  30
30.5698|  35.6893
```

Here in the above columns, the values with the decimals should be multiplied by 100 to convert them into whole numbers and the whole numbers should not be disturbed as they are in a correct format.

Using the converted whole numbers, the difference of the columns is calculated.

So I tried the mathematical function in hive say MOD function.

But using this function, the difference of the whole numbers is correct. But the difference of the decimals is wrong.

I don't know where i'm going wrong.

I tried the following code:

select mod(B,100)-mod(A,100) from sample

The actual result is:

```
A      |  B      |  C
0.33   |  0.55   |  22
0.44   |  0.65   |  21
10     |  20     |  10
10.1   |  10.234 |  13
11.236 |  12.8963|  166
12     |  30     |  18
30.5698|  35.6893|  512
```

Comment: Please add also the desired result

Comment: I have mentioned it saying The actual result is:

Answer (score 0):

What data type are A and B? 
If you define them as decimals, all the values will have the same presicion:

```
create  table temp.table_name           (                                                                                                                                                                                     
A                  decimal(10,5)  
,B                  decimal(10,5)  
)
stored as parquet location '../temp.db/table_name'
;

INSERT INTO TABLE temp.table_name 
  VALUES (0.33   ,0.55)
,(0.44   ,0.65)
,(10     ,20)
,(10.1   ,10.234)
,(11.236 ,12.8963)
,(12     ,30)
,(30.5698,35.6893);
```

Result of the select (All the data with the same precision):

```
+---------------+---------------+--+
| table_name.a  | table_name.b  |
+---------------+---------------+--+
| 0.33000       | 0.55000       |
| 0.44000       | 0.65000       |
| 10.00000      | 20.00000      |
| 10.10000      | 10.23400      |
| 11.23600      | 12.89630      |
| 12.00000      | 30.00000      |
| 30.56980      | 35.68930      |
+---------------+---------------+--+
```

Select to get the difference in decimals:

```
select a ,b ,( cast(round((b*100),0) as int) - 
 cast(round((a*100),0) as int)) as res
from temp.table_name;
```

Result - difference of the decimals:

```
+-----------+-----------+-------+--+
|     a     |     b     |  res  |
+-----------+-----------+-------+--+
| 0.33000   | 0.55000   | 22    |
| 0.44000   | 0.65000   | 21    |
| 10.00000  | 20.00000  | 1000  |
| 10.10000  | 10.23400  | 13    |
| 11.23600  | 12.89630  | 166   |
| 12.00000  | 30.00000  | 1800  |
| 30.56980  | 35.68930  | 512   |
+-----------+-----------+-------+--+
```

Hope that can help you.